# Possible to require custom module dependancy on a specific dev version?

Tags: 7

Is it possible for my custom module to enforce it's dependability on a specific dev version of a particular module?

E.g. my custom module, foo is dependant on variable module `7.x-1.1+26-dev`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the info. 
[Writing .info files (Drupal 7.x)](http://drupal.org/node/542202)

```
dependencies[] = exampleapi (1.x)
```

The above module requires any minor version of the module in the 1.x branch (1.0, 1.1, 1.2-beta4, etc.)

**The dependencies[] property in the .info file can also optionally specify operators:**

```
= or == equals (optional: equals is the default)
> greater than
< lesser than
>= greater than or equal to
<= lesser than or equal to
!= not equal to
```

Comment: OP asked for a specific dev revision of a module, not a minor version

Comment: @Clive Drupal packaging script adds version like `"7.x-1.1+0-dev"` So you can try `dependencies[] = exampleapi (7.x-1.1+0-dev)`

Comment: I didn't realise that, apologies :)

Comment: @Clive No Probs. Thumbs up.

Comment: Thanks @Clive for clarifying for me. I would have asked the same.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 7.x does not support development dependencies as tagged by drupal.org's packaging system. A development identifier (`+XX-dev`) will be removed from the dependency before a version comparison.  There are a couple surprises with the comparison, so it's worth detailing further.

### Dependency version parsing

The dependency's version, as found in a module's info file, is parsed by [`drupal_parse_dependency()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_parse_dependency/7.x). The version is separated into three parts via regular expressions.

```php
$p_core = '(?:' . preg_quote(DRUPAL_CORE_COMPATIBILITY) . '-)?';
$p_major = '(?P<major>\d+)';
$p_minor = '(?P<minor>(?:\d+|x)(?:-[A-Za-z]+\d+)?)';
```

The minor part may include an identifier (*alpha*, *beta*, *rc*) as long as it is preceded by `-` and followed by one or more decimal digits. Drupal packaging development identifier, which uses a + as separator, won't match the minor's identifier regex and it's removed. For example, `7.x-1.1+10-dev` will be simplified to `7.x-1.1`<sup>1</sup>.

### Version comparison

The version comparison happens in [`drupal_check_incompatibility()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_check_incompatibility/7.x), which uses two parameters:

- `$v`: The parsed dependency structure from `drupal_parse_dependency()`
- `$current_version`: The version to check against

The parsed `$v` will already have had any development identifiers removed, but `$current_version`, retrieved directly from the the module's .info file with the core (`7.x`) removed, may contain a development identifier. This doesn't typically cause problems because the actual version comparison, done by the internal PHP function [`version_compare()`](https://www.php.net/version_compare), converts the *+* separator to *.*:

> The function first replaces _, - and + with a dot . in the version strings and also inserts dots . before and after any non number so that for example '4.3.2RC1' becomes '4.3.2.RC.1'. Then it compares the parts starting from left to right. If a part contains special version strings these are handled in the following order: any string not found in this list < dev < alpha = a < beta = b < RC = rc < # < pl = p. This way not only versions with different levels like '4.1' and '4.1.2' can be compared but also any PHP specific version containing development state.

Therefore, the development module's development identifier becomes a patch number<sup>2</sup> with *dev* appended. For example, *1.1+10-dev* becomes *1.1.10.dev*.

Patch releases are greater than corresponding minor releases (*1.1.10.dev* > *1.1(.0)*), and because most dependencies specify a greater or equal version, the development module is marked compatible.

For example, `(>=7.x-1.1)` will be compatible with a *7.x-1.1+10-dev* will be compatible because `version_compare()` consider *1.1.10.dev* higher or equal to *1.1*.

However, the dependency `(==7.x-1.1+10-dev)` won't be compatible with *7.x-1.1+10-dev*.

<sup>1</sup> Technically, the core is also dropped and the actual comparison value would be *1.1*. I've retained the core for demonstrative purposes.

<sup>2</sup> I mean the semantic versioning's major, minor, and patch.